# Trouble with installing eclipse themes in OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, themes

I'm really new to OS X and I'm trying to set up Eclipse just like it looked on my Windows machine.

When I go to *Help → Eclipse Marketplace → Popular* and try to install "Darkest Dark Theme.." (link below) it gives me an error message, right after clicking on "install" and agreeing on the license stuff, which says "an error occurred while installing the items".

This is the message I get from the "details":

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=_Users_anton_eclipse_java-oxygen_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.genuitec.eclipse.common.core.base.feature.feature.jar 1.8.4.201709142212, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallFeatureAction).
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.
```

If have actually no idea what to do now and how to fix this.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue - do you still experience this problem if you try again? Can you tell us what your base version and distribution of Eclipse into which you are trying to install this is? (for example, Eclipse Oxygen JEE)